# Optimizing a boolean expression to (NAND,AND,NOT) system

Tags: karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra, nand

I'm trying to simplify the expression given by the following Karnaugh map to an expression that is using only NANDs, NOTs and ANDs- the less gates (of any kind), the better.

[image: Karnaugh Map]

I know how to optimize it to an (OR,AND,NOT) system, but that doesn't seem to help.

I also know how to create an OR gate using only NANDs and NOTs, but that creates a really complicated expression and I've been hinted there's a simple one.

I tried using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NAND%20%28~w%20%26%26%20~x%20%26%26%20~y%29%20%7C%7C%20%28~w%20%26%26%20x%20%26%26%20y%29%20%7C%7C%20%28w%20%26%26%20x%20%26%26%20z%29%20%7C%7C%20%28w%20%26%26%20~x%20%26%26%20~z%29), but no (AND,NAND,NOT) system exist. The closest one is a (NAND, NOT) system and that expression still looks complicated.

I'm allowed 4 inputs per NAND and 2 inputs per AND.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many inputs are you allowed per gate? Unspecified?

Comment: Start with getting the POS expression. In your case you will get from the K-map 4 3-var sums, while each of them can be transformed to a 3-input-NAND representation using the DeMorgan rule. So without any further manual simplifications, I am getting here 4 NOT gates, 4 3-input NANDS and one 4-input AND - total of 9 gates.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sorry, I haven't specified that. I'm allowed 2 inputs per AND and 4 inputs per NAND.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks! As I've now added I'm only allowed 2 inputs per AND, so although I could part the AND in your solution to 2 ANDs maybe there's a better solution under these conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complement Law says \$\overline{\overline{X}} = X\$.

$$\overline A\ \overline B\ \overline C + \overline A\ B\ C + A\ B\ D + A\ \overline B\ \overline D$$

Take Double Complement.
$$\overline{\overline{\overline A\ \overline B\ \overline C + \overline A\ B\ C + A\ B\ D + A\ \overline B\ \overline D}}$$

Use DeMorgan's to remove lower complement.
$$\overline{\overline{\overline A\ \overline B\ \overline C} ∙ \overline{\overline A\ B\ C} ∙ \overline{A\ B\ D} ∙ \overline{A\ \overline B\ \overline D}}$$

4 NOTs, 4 3-input NANDs, 1 4-input NAND.